# How to change the TextInputEditText floating hint color when not focused

Tags: android, styling, android-textinputlayout

I am trying to create an TextInputEditText whose floating hint color will not change when not focused.
The color of the hint is changing from white to blue ie to the color set through `textColorHint` field.

[image]

It is only happening when the TextInputEditText is filled and not focused. I want the hint to be white when above the TextInputEditText and blue when inside the box.
When the TextInputEditText is not empty and not focused the hint color is turning blue.

[image]

**TextInputEditText**

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/app_blue"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/fNameET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/text_input_layout_background"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:hint="First Name"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

**TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout**

```
    <style name="TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

And I want to use xml to do the above task not java.

Comment: In my experience you can apply a style for not focused state, but it is the same if the field is empty or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this code into your style.xml file ->

```
<style name="TextLabelDummy" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>  // Text Color
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/blue</item>    // Hint Color
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>    //Floating label color
    </style>
```

You can change the parent attribute whatever you want. I've randomly used the "Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.Dense"

Then call this as theme into you layout file

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/textInputLayoutNumberDummy"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabelDummy">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/textInputEditTextNumberDummy"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/text_mobile" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

It worked fine on my side. Just check it and let me know about it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Works like a charm

Comment: I'm getting `The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).`.

Comment: You have to use the "Material Design" dependency for this in your gradle file. Have you added it?

Answer (score 1):

Add style in your TextInputLayout

```
 <style name="TextLabel">
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/dark_gray</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/color_Black</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">false</item>
        <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>
   </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add hintTextColor in TextInputLayout

```
app:hintTextColor="@color/black"
```

Answer (score 0):

add `app:hintTextAppearance` style like this:

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    ......
      app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"
    ......>
```

and

```
 <style name="TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">top color</item>
  </style>
```

UPDATE:

you also need to set EditText theme like this:

```
android:theme="@style/InputText.Light"
```

and

```
 <style name="InputText.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorHighlight">top color</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Yes @Antonis Radz I have done the same thing. But    `android:textColorHint="@color/app_blue"` line is overriding the style.

Comment: hmm, in my case textColorHint is primary color when it is not have focus and it is at the bottom, and color in custom style is shown when it has focus and it is above EditText

Answer (score 0):

I changed focused color with reflection. Here's the snippet it may help someone.

```
private void setUpperHintColor(int color) {
try {
    Field field = textInputLayout.getClass().getDeclaredField("mFocusedTextColor");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    int[][] states = new int[][]{
            new int[]{}
    };
    int[] colors = new int[]{
            color
    };
    ColorStateList myList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
    field.set(textInputLayout, myList);

    Method method = textInputLayout.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("updateLabelState", boolean.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(textInputLayout, true);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> create custom theme for **`TextInputLayout`** like below

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutHint" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/your color</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>
</style>
```

And apply it to **`TextInputLayout`** like below.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutHint"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this a bit so I wrote a sample and tried a few things until I got it working.

My layout doesn't have anything special:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/user_agent_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="hint text"
        android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And my styles look like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="textInputStyle">@style/myedit1</item>
</style>


<style name="myedit1" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/myHint</item>

</style>

<style name="myHint" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textColor">#1111dd</item>
</style>
```

Basically `<item name="textInputStyle">@style/myedit1</item>` points to the `TextInputLayout` style and in there `hintTextAppearance` to the hint style.